# forced to use QT5_WRAP_CPP macro instead of automoc property in cmake

Tags: cmake, qt5, qobject

According to the [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html) I should be able to only use a property rather than having to wrap my header files, which contain a Q_OBJECT macro like in the following cmake snippet. If I use the wrapping macro the code compiles and runs but if I use only the enabled property, I get a compiler error

> ../gui/libgui.so: undefined reference to `vtable for ImageWidget'

why is that?

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project (app)

#QT5_WRAP_CPP(MOC_files
#       ../gui/include/gui/imageWidget.hpp
#)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
    #  ${MOC_files}
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES AUTOMOC TRUE)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
     PRIVATE
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Xml
    Qt5::OpenGL
    Qt5::Gui
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES 
    INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN:${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib:$ORIGIN/")

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: Description of *AUTOMOC* property lists exact cases, when `moc` is called automatically. Are you sure that one of which cases is applicable for your case? If yes, which one?

Comment: thank you, so I just need to prepend my filenames containing a Q_OBJECT Macro like "moc_imageWidget.cpp" instead of "imageWidget.cpp" and it should work?

Comment: May be. It is difficult to say anything without viewing the code.

Comment: You need to add the header files to your `add_executable` call. `moc` then processes all headers to find the releveant ones.

Comment: bu this doesnt alleviateany effort, since I still mention the headers explicitly then

Comment: Indeed, you need to mention all components (headers, source files, resources, forms) that belong to your target in the `add_executable` call. Otherwise, how should `moc`, `uic`, `rcc` know?

Comment: of course, but now I have to mention both! the header and the sources in the script instead of only the sources and a call `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
 ...`

Comment: `target_include_directories` is only for providing information where to search for headers not what headers should be included. Without a dependency analysis of your cpp files moc cannot know.