# Qt Quick + CMake + custom QObject results in undefined reference to `vtable'

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, qtquick2

I use Qt Quick to make small application to work with files.
Everything was working until one moment i executed in my `build/` folder

```
rm -rf * 
cmake ..
make
```

And then make halted with this error (lising is huge, i suppresed non-important part):

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable uint32_sort_gui

In function `LibController::~LibController()':
lib_controller.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `vtable for LibController'
main.cpp.o: In function `int qmlRegisterType<LibController>(char const*, int, int, char const*)':

...
```

Here is my `.hpp` and `.cpp` files of the class:

> lib_controller.hpp

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class LibController : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(decltype(getProgress) progress READ getProgress NOTIFY ProgressChanged)
    public:
        explicit LibController(QObject *parent = 0);
        ~LibController(); 

        double getProgress();

        Q_INVOKABLE
        void addFile(QString from_name, QString to_name);
        Q_INVOKABLE
        void sortFile();
    signals:
        void ProgressChanged();

    private:
        double current_progress;
        FileManager* file_manager;
};
```

> lib_controller.cpp

```
#include "lib_controller.hpp"

LibController::~LibController(){
    delete file_manager;
}

double LibController::getProgress(){...}

void LibController::addFile(QString from_name, QString to_name){...}

void LibController::sortFile(){...}
```

> main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>

#include "lib_controller.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Registration of custom type
    qmlRegisterType<LibController>("com.sort.controller", 0, 1, "LibController");

    ...

    return app.exec();
}
```

And my [CMakeLists.txt](https://pastebin.com/vxcGBMKp) configuration.

I read another questions about this problem, but cleaning and rebuilding did not help (i even accidentally deleted whole project folder).

The problem persists, and i do not understand, how to fix it ...

**UPD:**

Here is [full error message](https://pastebin.com/SEiQqbA7)

**UPD2:**

After excluded `LibController` from the project and recompiling it, error is gone, but no window is showed to me. I can see from terminal that it is running, but no GUI popped up.

I guess problem is not in `LibController`, but somewhere else.

Comment: do you `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` in your CMake file? This linker error is often caused by moc not processing your header file.

Comment: @Mike yup. I added CMakeLists.txt to post

Comment: I am still suspicious of moc not being invoked for your header file for some reason. Can you verify that by running `make VERBOSE=1` and examine the executed command?

Comment: Also, the rest of the linker error message might give a clue about the function whose definition is missing (e.g. is it `LibController::staticMetaObject`?). Could you append it to your question?

Comment: @Mike well, there is `[ 50%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target uint32_sort_gui` line. I uploaded complete output to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kNvgt7Mj)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing location of header file causes missing vtable error when compiling with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435647/changing-location-of-header-file-causes-missing-vtable-error-when-compiling-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add headers to the list of your source files for cmake to be able to run AUTOMOC on them.

This question has been already asked and answered here [Changing location of header file causes missing vtable error when compiling with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56435647/3344612)

Answer (score 0):

Since you call out the constructor in your header try adding this to the cpp file:

```
LibController::LibController(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
}
```

Also, I have found that Rebuild All doesn't re-run qmake all the time. If you still see the issue run Build, Run qmake to make sure the header is getting processed.

Comment: Sorry, but this do not help, the message is the same. Also i use not qmake, but CMake. I every time i delete everything in the `build/` folder, then run `cmake .. ; make`

Answer (score 0):

According to comments in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027620/forced-to-use-qt5-wrap-cpp-macro-instead-of-automoc-property-in-cmake) question, you should

1. Rename your custom object header file to `moc_*your header name*.hpp`
2. Add path to this header to `add_executable()` function
3. Clear `build/` directory and rerun CMake
4. Be somewhat happy in the end of the day

Hope this will help somebody, who tried to find last resort, like me.